# MagicMock Mock'ed Function is not 'called'

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I an trying to mock an api function `send_message` from `stmplib.SMTP` in Python using MagicMock.

a simplified version of my function looks like

```
#email_sender.py
def sendMessage():
    msg = EmailMessage()
    #Skipping code for populating msg

    with smtplib.SMTP("localhost") as server:
        server.send_message(msg)
```

I want to mock `server.send_message` call for my unit test. I have searched SO for some pointers and tried to follow a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72756380/8312634).

Here is my unit test code based on the above question:

```
#email_sender_test.py
import email_sender as es
def test_send_message_input_success() -> None:
with patch("smtplib.SMTP", spec=smtplib.SMTP) as mock_client:
    mock_client.configure_mock(
        **{
            "send_message.return_value": None
        }
    )
    
    es.sendMessage()
    
    #assert below Passes
    assert mock_client.called == True
    
    #assert below Fails
    assert mock_client.send_message.called == True
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong which is causing the `assert mock_client.send_message.called == True` to fail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the wrong mock attribute. Your code doesn’t call `smtplib.SMTP.send_message`. It might do so *indirectly* with the real object but a Mock can’t actually be sure of that nor should you want it to be that magical.

Take a look at what your code does with the `smtp.SMTP` mock; this is important because you’ll need to follow the same path in your test setup:

- the mock is called: `smtplib.SMTP("localhost")`. Calling a mock will return a new mock object to stand in as the instance.
- the instance mock is used as a context manager: `with ... as server:`. Python calls the [`__enter__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__) and the return value of that method is bound to the name given by `as`. The instance mock will produce a new mock object for this. In fact, even the `.__enter__` attribute is a mock object standing in for the method object.
- The context manager mock, finally, is used to send the message: `server.send_message(...)`.

The mock library actually creates these extra mock objects just once, then reuses them whenever needed, *and* you can access them in your setup, via the [`Mock.return_value` attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value). You can use these to follow the same trail:

```py
with patch("smtplib.SMTP", spec=smtplib.SMTP) as mock_smtp:
    mock_instance = mock_smtp.return_value  # smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
    mock_cm = mock_instance.__enter__.return_value  # with ... as server

    # set up the server.send_message call return value
    mock_cm.send_message.return_value = None

    # run the function-under-test
    es.sendMessage()

    # assert things were called
    assert mock_cm.send_message.called
```

Note: there is no need to add `== True`; that’s just doubling up on testing if true is true to produce true. `assert` already takes care of the check for you.

You can try these things out in an interactive interpreter too:

```py
>>> import smtplib
>>> from unittest.mock import patch
>>> patcher = patch("smtplib.SMTP", spec=smtplib.SMTP)
>>> mock_smtp = patcher.start()  # same as what with patch() as ... does
>>> smtplib.SMTP
<MagicMock name='SMTP' spec='SMTP' id='4356608448'>
>>> smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
<NonCallableMagicMock name='SMTP()' spec='SMTP' id='4356726496'>
>>> with smtplib.SMTP("localhost") as server:
...     pass
... 
>>> server
<MagicMock name='SMTP().__enter__()' id='4356772768'>
>>> server.send_message("some argument")  # not set to return None here
<MagicMock name='SMTP().__enter__().send_message()' id='4356805728'>
>>> mock_smtp.return_value.__enter__.return_value.send_message.called
True
```

Note how each new mock object has a name that reflects how we got there! For future tests, try printing mocked objects in your code-under-test to see how to reach the right objects in your test setup, or use a debugger to inspect the objects. It’ll help you figure out what is going on.